# Is "be" really required after "may" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

I read a sentence in "The Hindu" which was:

> Age maybe has slowed down MT Vasudevan Nair but his creativity remains undiminished.

I think it is an egregious error to use may be this style. Shouldn't there be just "may" before "slowed down"?

Comment: It is needed if you wish to phrase the sentence like that. If you want to get rid of the 'be', 'has' must be converted to 'have'.

Comment: The single-word form ***maybe*** is effectively an adverbial element (either modifying the specific verb ***to slow down***, or a "sentence adverb" modifying the entire assertion up to ***but*** here). But ***may*** is a kind of degenerate "modal" verb itself, so it requires an *[unmarked] **infinitive*** verb form, as in *The groom may **kiss** the bride* (as opposed to *The groom **kisses** the bride*).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a cross-post of the [identical question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/210659/is-be-really-required-after-may-in-this-sentence) at ELL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Maybe* is fine.

It functions as an [adverb](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/maybe) meaning "possibly" and modifies the verb phrase "has slowed down." I can't speak for Indian English, but in American English "maybe" immediately preceding a verb would hit a lower register than "maybe" at the head of a clause. (Compare: "Maybe age has slowed down ...")

Here are two other examples found through [the Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) out of several dozen. "Maybe" preceding a verb crops up in more speech than writing (most results involve live news programs):

> ("Rebel on the Edge," *Time*, 1/23/2006.) He is the world's best ski racer, but whatever the result, he laughs it off and **maybe** has a beer afterward.
>
> ("United Shades of America: Off the Grid," *CNN*, 5/22/2016.) And so what would you say to somebody whose sitting at home right now, who **maybe** has just seen this for the first time and is going huh?

Answer (score 0):

It's poor (or at least very informal). I would prefer something like:

> Age has perhaps slowed down...

I'd prefer that over "Age may have slowed down..." also.